# Asp.net Web.config - Moving the sitemap provider outside the web.config

Tags: asp.net, web-config, sitemap

We can move our connectionStrings to a separate file ie:

```
<connectionStrings configSource="ConnectionStrings.config"/>
```

It would be useful to move the sitemap section outside of web.config

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
<providers>
.... add ther providers here name here....
</providers>
</siteMap>
```

I currently add an `<add name="" ..... />` inside the `<providers>` section and add a sitemap to the site.

A site with many pages with diverse menus benefit from many sitemaps.

I would like to add them without having to update the web.config.  (IE put and add in this section in its own code and add the new sitemap.)

vs2008 intellisense does show configSource as valid, but I have not been able to get this to work.

Is it allowed implemented in web.config?  If so an example of working code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have it working: 
The Web.config now has a line:

```
<siteMap configSource="MySiteMaps.config" />
```

And I now have a file Called MySiteMaps.config containing:

```
 <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
  <providers>
       <add name="XmlName1" description="desc1" etc.../>
       <add name="XmlName2" description="desc2" etc.../>
  </providers>
 </sitemap>
```

Works just fine.

The only issue for me is the little blue line under the siteMap element in the MySiteMaps.config file. "The 'siteMap' element is not declaired."
Hope this helps!

I am researching the blue squigly line.  I could live with it, but I don't like loose ends.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about adding the sitemap information to the web.config, but it does look like you can use multiple sitemap files.  The default sitemap file is web.sitemap and then you can add any number of child sitemap files.

See this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178426(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: I am trying to mode the add sitemap out of the web.config file.  The Web.config contains the references to the many sitemaps that I am useing.  Just trying to simplify by not having to put a new Web.Config on the site when I need to add a new sitemap.

Comment: I have it working: 
The Web.config now has a line:
      <siteMap configSource="MySiteMaps.config" />
And I now have a file Called MySiteMaps.config containing:
     <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>

Comment: I have it working: 
The Web.config now has a line:
      <siteMap configSource="MySiteMaps.config" />
And I now have a file Called MySiteMaps.config containing:
     <siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true">
          <providers>
               <add name="XmlName1" description="desc1" etc.../>
               <add name="XmlName2" description="desc2" etc.../>
          </providers>
     </sitemap>

Works just fine.

The only issue for me is the little blue line under the siteMap element in the MySiteMaps.config file. "The 'siteMap' element is not declaired."
Hope this helps!

Comment: This seems to be a common problem in my searching.  Making the siteMap line look like `<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">` does cause the blue squiggle to go away in my testing, but I don't know if that has any effect on functionality as I don't have a working repo handy.